# How to draw a 3D Plot with non-numerical axes?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I've got a CSV file that looks like this:

```
c1,c2,m1,m2,m3
'a','b',1,0.5,4
...
'x','y',10,100,4.21
```

Where `c1` & `c2` are 'coordinates' and `m`s are values of 3 different functions (each one - of two arguments (c1, c2)).

Is it possible to build a 3D Plot containing values of this `m`s (all at once), where axes are labelled `'a', ..., 'x'` and `'b', ..., 'y'`?

*Update*: seeing as my question needs clarification, let's assume for the sake of simplicity that there is only one `m` in the table.

```
c1,c2,m1
'a','b',1,0.5,4
'b','a',2,3,4
'x','y',10,100,4.21
'y','x',12,20,40
```

Now, I'd like to draw a 3D plot, where X-axis and Y-axis would be labeled with `a, b, x, y`, and Z-axis will be an ordinary real-valued axis (with values from e.g. 0 to 150), and each value of the `m` column would be located at coordinates e. g. ('a', 'b', 1).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Please clarify your question, which I (at least) have trouble understanding.  Thanks.

Comment: I too feel this question needs clarification.  Among other things you say a 3D plot yet you only indicate two axes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data = {
  {"a", "b", 1, 0.5, 4},
  {"x", "y", 10, 100, 4.21}
};
numericdata = data;
numericdata[[All, 1]] = Range[1, Length[numericdata]]; (**)
numericdata[[All, 2]] = Range[1, Length[numericdata]]; (**)
ListPointPlot3D[
  {
    numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 3}]],
    numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 4}]],
    numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 5}]]
  },
  Ticks -> {
    Transpose[{numericdata[[All, 1]], data[[All, 1]]}],
    Transpose[{numericdata[[All, 2]], data[[All, 2]]}],
    Automatic
  }
]
```

The lines marked with `(**)` are to be modified by you, depending on what numbers you want those characters to be mapped to for plotting purpose. In the example I use `{1, 2}` for both `{"a", "x"}` and `{"b", "y"}`.

And if you'd like the points to be connected by lines, you can start from the following example:

```
Graphics3D[
  {
    PointSize[Large],
    Red,
    Through@{Point, Line}[numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 3}]]],
    Green,
    Through@{Point, Line}[numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 4}]]],
    Blue,
    Through@{Point, Line}[numericdata[[All, {1, 2, 5}]]]
  },
  Axes -> True,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  Ticks -> {
    Transpose[{numericdata[[All, 1]], data[[All, 1]]}],
    Transpose[{numericdata[[All, 2]], data[[All, 2]]}],
    Automatic
  }
]
```

[image: alternative to ListLinePlot3D]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. I got this image: https : // i.imgur.com/ELDnBFi.png using your method, it looks pretty much as I wanted it to. Is there by any chance a possibility to connect those dots with the line? I tried using `ListPlot3D`, but the output was an empty box.

Comment: I've updated the answer for that. Use `Graphics3D` instead of `ListPointPlot3D`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted.